# How to fix Text widget overflow issue to show the overflowed text in next line?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

My title Text widget is overflowing and hiding my price Text widget, I want these both Text widget in same row and when the title contains max numbers of characters then I want to show this in next line, how can I fix it. I am attaching image of overflowing text.

Here is my code:

```
 new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Column(

                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0)),
                          new Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment:  MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: <Widget>[

                              new Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  new Text(productList[index].name,

                                    style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black,
                                        fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  )

                                ],
                              ),


                              new Text("€"+productList[index].price.toString(),
                                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black,
                                    fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                ),),

                            ],
                          )


                        ],
                      ),

                      new Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Flexible(
                              child: new Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start ,
                                children: <Widget>[

                                  new Text(

                                    productList[index].description,
                                    overflow:  TextOverflow.fade ,),
                                ],
                              ))
                        ],
                      ),

                      new Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: <Widget>[
                         new  ListTileItemAddRemove(productList[index]),


                          new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0))
                        ],
                      )


                    ],
                  ),
                  new Divider(color: Colors.black,)
                ],
              ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I fixed this issue:

```
return new Container(

                      child: new Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),


                            child: new Column(

                              children: <Widget>[
                                new Column(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0)),
                                    new Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:  MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: <Widget>[

                                        new Container(
                                          alignment: FractionalOffset.topLeft ,
                                          width: 250.0,
                                          child: new Column(
                                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              new Text(productList[index].name,

                                                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black,
                                                    fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                              )

                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),


                                        new Text("£"+productList[index].price.toString(),
                                          style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black,
                                              fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                          ),),

                                      ],
                                    )


                                  ],
                                ),

                                new Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    new Flexible(
                                        child: new Column(
                                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start ,
                                          children: <Widget>[

                                            new Text(

                                              productList[index].description,
                                              overflow:  TextOverflow.fade ,),
                                          ],
                                        ))
                                  ],
                                ),

                                new Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    new  ListTileItemAddRemove(productList[index]),


                                    new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0))
                                  ],
                                )


                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          new Divider(color: Colors.black,)
                        ],
                      ),

                    );
```